# Where exactly do locales "reside"?

Tags: php, windows, cross-platform, locale, icu

I think I'm losing my mind. I've just read a ton of confusing information on ICU's website, starting here: http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale

I'm utterly confused about what a "resource bundle" is, but it doesn't seem to mean "a bunch of locale files" which I first thought.

Where exactly do "locales" live? When I list locales in PHP, which allegedly uses ICU data, is that the data from the PHP distribution, or is it grabbing it from my OS (Windows 10)? So it would differ depending on which OS/computer I run my application? Or is it the same between environments as long as they all use (the same version of) PHP?

Also, I have never seen any of those locales which specify a "script code" and "variant code". It's always just "en_US", for example. "language_location". If those exist, they certainly aren't listed for me. I'm probably going to just entirely ignore that whole concept unless somebody straightens that out.

What am I missing?! Where exactly do locales live/exist/reside? Where does the data come from? Do they all use this "ICU" data? Do they redundantly make "distributions" or "bundles" of locales? If so, why? Can I download a huge list of ALL locales, smack them into a dir and tell PHP to use those instead of whatever it is currently using?

I have also read the PHP manual on this a lot without finding this information anywhere.

Comment: Which locales. Notepad's MUI (multi language Interface) the UI elements with text are stored for English C:\windows\system32\en-us\notepad.exe.mui. It will load from here if an English configured computer starts it and from another folder (de-de) if german. If you are talking about your program you have to do something similar, usually a dll file that you load with text based on the language your program wants to do. The data is in System32 in *.nls files. Although locales are a subset of NLS (National Language Support). See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/nls-terminology

Comment: The [ICU docs](http://userguide.icu-project.org/icudata#TOC-Sharing-ICU-Data-Between-Platforms) claim that by default it's bundled with an 8 MiB data set (e.g. converter mapping tables, collation rules, transliteration rules, break iterator rules and dictionaries, and other locale data). The next step is to determine whether PHP bundles the default or a custom data set and how it's integrated. (Sorry, I know practically nothing about the design and implementation of PHP.)